# JavaScript Form Validation not working entirely

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, debugging

I am trying to have JavaScript code validate all the elements of this form but for some reason the select box doesn't validated. The user can fill in all the blanks except for the select box and the JavaScript does not catch it. Any ideas as to what I am missing? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
var ageErr = document.getElementById('ageErr');
var nameErr = document.getElementById('nameErr');
var radioErr = document.getElementById('radioErr');
var results = document.getElementById('results');
var theName = document.formContact.theName;
var theAge = document.formContact.theAge;
var theRadioGp = document.formContact.contact;
var theSelect = document.formContact.theSelect;
var chkValue;
if(theName.value =="") {
   nameErr.innerHTML = "A name is required ";
   theName.focus();
   return false;
}else {
   nameErr.innerHTML= "";
}
if(theAge.value ==""){
   ageErr.innerHTML = "An age is required";
   theAge.focus();
   return false;
}else {
   nameErr.innerHTML = "";
}
if(theAge.vale =="") {
   age.Err.innerHTML = "An age is required";
   theAge.focus();
   return false;
} else if (isNaN(theAge.value)) {
   ageErr.innerHTML = "Age should be a number";
    theAge.select();
} else if (theAge.value < 3 || theAge.value > 120) {
   ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your real Age";
   theAge.select();
   return false;
} else{
    ageErr.innerHTML = "";
}
for(var i=0; i < theRadioGp.length; i++) {
   if(theRadioGp[i].checked ==true) {
   chkValue = theRadioGp[i].value;
   }
}
if(chkValue == undefined) {
   alert('You need to slect a method of contact');
   return false;
 }
if(theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text == "<--PLEASE SELECT ONE-->")
{alert("You need to select an option");
   return false;
  }else {
    alert("Your have selected "+theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text);
  }
  alert("Your form has been completed. Great Job!!");
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="formContact" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" name="formContact">
 <p>Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="theName"><span class="err" id="nameErr"></span>
 </p>
 <p>Age:<br />
    <input type="text" name="theAge"><span class="err" id="ageErr"></span>
 </p>
 <p>
 <p>How may we contact you?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">Email<br>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="no contact">No Contact<br>
 </p>
 <p>Please coose a selection below:<br>
   <select name="theSelect">
      <option>&lt;--PLEASE SELECT ONE --&gt;
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit" ">

</form>

<span id="results"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `===` instead of two `==`?

Comment: Is this just a typo in your code here? `if(theAge.vale ==""){` is missing the "u" in `value`.

Comment: Yes, I just tried that but no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML isn't valid. Replace your select part with following

```
<select name="theSelect">
    <option>&lt;--PLEASE SELECT ONE--&gt;</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Or use a numeric value for the default option

```
<select name="theSelect">
    <option value="0">PLEASE SELECT AN OPTION</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And check the value (not the text selected)

```
if(theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value == 0){
    alert("You need to select an option");
    return false;
}else {
    alert("Your have selected " + theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use selectedIndex without the text?

Example:

```
<select id="mytest">
 <option value="-1"><--PLEASE SELECT ONE--></option>
 <option value="1">Test One</option>
 <option value="2">Test Two</option>
</select>
```

Then

```
if(theSelect.selectedIndex == -1)
{alert("You need to select an option");
   return false;
  }else {
the rest
```